# On making the environment depend on the current directory

Tags: zsh, environment-variables

I think it would be useful/convenient if the current directory determined one's shell environment.  This would mean that the command

```
cd /my/projects/foo
```

..., for example, would not only set the current working directory (and update `$PWD`, `$OLDPWD`, `$dirstack`, etc.), but would also adjust a host of other environment elements (shell options, variables, functions, aliases, etc.) in a manner appropriate to the contents of the new `PWD`.

At first blush this seems like a relatively simple thing to implement, especially with `zsh`, since it already supports a `chpwd` hook, and the `$chpwd_functions` array.  But, as they say, the devil is in the details<sup>1</sup>.

Therefore, before plunging into rolling my own, I thought I'd ask: is anyone aware of a mature implementation of this idea?

Alternatively, besides `chpwd` et al., does `zsh` provide other tools that would be helpful towards implementing such a thing?  In particular, does it provide any support for encapsulating/saving/restoring environments?  (I'm thinking of something in the vein of `R`'s environment objects, but encompassing not only variables, but also, e.g., aliases, options, etc.)

---

FWIW, I am aware of Python's `virtualenv`, which shares some features with the idea described in this post, but of course, this is limited to Python-related settings, however.  Furthermore, it creates a new "state variable", if you will, the "current virtual environment", orthogonal (rather subsumed under) the "current working directory" state variable.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Once one looks into the matter more carefully one quickly meets some non-trivial questions.  For example: if `cd`'ing to `/my/projects/foo` activates a custom environment, what exactly happens after `cd /my/projects/foo/modules/bar`?  Can we have nested custom environments, demarcated by the filesystem's tree structure?  What about symlinks?  E.g., what if `/my/projects/foo/modules/bar` is actually a symlink to `/my/shared/modules/bar`?  Or, if I execute `/my/projects/foo/some_program` while `$PWD` is `/tmp`, say, what should be the environment of the resulting process?  Etc., etc., etc.  I don't find these questions necessarily intractable, but I do find them at least not-totally-trivial.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

There're mature tools designed to set environment variables for a specific directory.

Compared with other tools designed for this, [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) is the best of them. One of the main benefit is that it supports **unload**ing the environment variables when you exit from that directory.

> `direnv` is an environment switcher for the shell. It knows how to hook into bash, zsh, tcsh, fish shell and elvish to load or **unload** environment variables depending on the current directory. This allows **project-specific environment** variables without cluttering the `~/.profile` file.

What makes `direnv` distinct between other similar tools:

- `direnv` is written in Go, **faster** compared with its counterpart written in Python
- `direnv` supports **unload**ing environment variables when you quit from the specific dir
- `direnv` covers many shells

Similar projects

- [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) - one of the oldest (in a good way) environment-loading systems
- [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) - lightweight; doesn't support unloads; slow written in Python
- [zsh-autoenv](https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-autoenv) - a feature-rich mixture of autoenv and [smartcd](https://github.com/cxreg/smartcd): enter/leave events, nesting, stashing (Zsh-only).
- [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) - a pure bash solution that has a plugin system

Comment: You posted this exact same answer on the duplicate question (which is how I found out that they were duplicates).  The appropriate action would have been to post the answer on one of the questions and to flag the other question as a duplicate for review.